# Adding all elements of an list in a dynamic table vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Protected Sub createTable()
    Try

        Dim listB As New ArrayList()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim info As SessioneUtente = Session(SessionVariables.InformazioniUtente)
        Dim id As String = info.getIdDisciplinaDefault.ToString
        dt = operations.G_Number(id)

        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            notifica.Text = "There is no number for this id"

        Else

            For Each row In dt.Rows
                list.Add(row(0))
                listB.Add(row(0))
            Next
            listB.Add(23)
            listB.Add(24)
            listB.Add(25)

            Dim cell1 As New TableCell
            Dim cell2 As New TableCell
            Dim Nr As New Label
            Dim Icon As New Label
            Dim row1 As New TableRow
            Dim row2 As New TableRow
            For Each item In listB
                If list.Contains(item) Then    
                    Nr.Text = item
                   Icon.Text = "<img = src='../Images/Icon1.png' />"
                    cell1.Controls.Add(Nr)
                    cell2.Controls.Add(Icon)
                    row1.Cells.Add(cell1)
                    row2.Cells.Add(cell2)
                Else
                   Nr.Text = item & vbLf
                    Icon.Text = "<img = src='../Images/Icon2.png' />"
                    cell1.Controls.Add(Nr)
                    cell2.Controls.Add(Icon)
                    row1.Cells.Add(cell1)
                    row2.Cells.Add(cell2)
                End If

            Next
            tabel.Rows.Add(row1)
            tabel.Rows.Add(row2)
            notifica.Visible = False

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim log As New Log
        log.writeLog("default", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm dynamically populating a table via VB.NET using an arraylist but the table gets only the last element of the list. The list takes some elements from database and the other I add by myself. I need some help about displaying all the element of the list in the dynamic table. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your current progress? Did you tried something already?

Comment: Mina, welcome to stack overflow. Please show us the code where you are attempting to add the list items to the table so we can help you. Edit your question and paste your code into the question and [] button.

Comment: What kind of table are you populating? A database table or a HTML table? The question is pretty unclear and we don't know what you did wrong because there is no code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Unless this is homework or an old app that you can't change, don't use an `ArrayList` at all.  That class has been obsolete since 2005.

Comment: This is what I have tried. In the table must be as cells as it has listB. Each cell will be populated with a number and for each number a respectively icon.

Answer (score 0):

I would try moving my variables that I was dimensioning inside of my foreach loop. It appears to me that you are overwriting them each time. You seem to be overwriting the same memory location on each loop. Moving them inside of the loop should create a new memory location for each item in the list. I am guessing that you are seeing the correct number of rows but they all have the same values which happen to be the last item in the list. This is because it is being overwritten and there are only pointers to that memory location being added on each loop. You also need to move where you are adding it into the table inside of the loop for each iteration because right now you are only adding the last thing you set the row to and when you move those variables into the loop it is going to throw you an error. You want to add each row into the table while it is in scope with the current data.